# Two of the same value in a set

Tags: python, set

so as I understand it sets are just supposed to be able to store unique values, but I manage to add two of the same values - {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '1', '4', '2', '5', '3'}

How is this possible?

Comment: One is an integer and one is a string. They arent the same.

Comment: 1 != '1', first is int, second is string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and '1' are not the same value. 1 is a integer, and '1' is a string. So your set does only contain unique values

Answer (score 0):

Whenever comparing two values,

First, check if two values have the same type.

Try this to double check.

```
if type(1) == type('1'):
    print('They have the same type')
else:
    print('They are not the same')
```

and this too

```
if 1 == '1':
    print('They are the same')
else:
    print('They are not the same')
```